# Interpreting $S_{N} \wr D_{m}$

Tags: symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product, direct-product, wreath-product

I am trying to interpret $S_{N} \wr D_{m}$ in the light of the interpretation of $\mathbb{Z}^n_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}_2$ in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9812070).

[image]

So, according to the definition,

$$\mathbb{Z}^n_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}_2 = (\mathbb{Z}^n_2 \times \mathbb{Z}^n_2) \rtimes  \mathbb{Z}_2 $$

Here, $N = (\mathbb{Z}^n_2 \times \mathbb{Z}^n_2)$ is the group of ordered pairs of binary strings of length $n$. And $N \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ is the group of ordered pairs of elements from $(\mathbb{Z}^n_2 \times \mathbb{Z}^n_2)$ with $0$ or $1$.

Assuming my interpretation is correct here is my attempt to interpret $S_{N} \wr D_{m}$.

$S_{N} \wr D_{m}$ is the group of ordered pairs of elements from $S_N$ with the elements of $D_m$.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: No. In the example with $\Bbb{Z}_2^n\wr \Bbb{Z}_2$ you get **pairs** of elements from $\Bbb{Z}_2^n$ because the group $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is acting on a set of **two** elements. In other words, viewed as a subgroup of $S_2$. If we view $D_m$ as a subgroup of $S_m$, then $S_N\wr D_m$ is the semidirect product $(S_N)^m\rtimes D_m$ with $D_m$ acting on the $m$-fold cartesian power by permuting the components.